# Как объединять сториборды в один проект?

Tags: swift, xcode, storyboard

Начал создавать проект в сториборд с помощью навигэйшн вью. Не особо разобравшись в сторибордах именно, не хочу переделывать проект(достаточно сделал уже), начал тупить мак от нагрузки. Хочу теперь добавлять новые сториборды, но в новом файле. Можно создать в разных файлах, а после как-то объединить в один проект ?

Comment: Пожалуйста, уточните вашу конкретную проблему или приведите более подробную информацию о том, что именно вам нужно. В текущем виде сложно понять, что именно вы спрашиваете.

Comment: можно, просто в сториборде нужно будет указать файл viewcontroller к которому хотите подвязать сториборд

Comment: Это не ваш случай? https://stackoverflow.com/a/30435605/5479247